# Installing azure in Python

Tags: python, azure, pip, conda

I then tried to install azure package on the command line and got the following error:

```
C:\Windows\system32>conda install azure

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: -
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
Examining @/win-64::__archspec==1=x86_64:  40%|████████████████▊                         | 2/5 [00:00<00:00, 14.11it/s]|failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - azure -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0']

Your python: python=3.8

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.
```

It seems to say it's not compatible with my more recent version of Python. Does anyone know how to install the package properly with Python 3.8?

(Within the azure package, I specifically need azure.functions as func and azure.storage.queue.QueueService.)

Comment: I think you have to change the your python version. To do that you have to uninstall the current python and install another version that its compatible with this lib.

Comment: Is there a way to change my python version without uninstalling and reinstalling Python on my entire computer? Changing the Python version would cause other programs that rely on Python 3 to stop working.

Answer (score 2):

The [`azure` package](https://pypi.org/project/azure/) you're trying to install has been deprecated since April 2020 and likely won't receive future updates. From the linked pypi page:

> Starting with v5.0.0, this package is deprecated. Please install the service specific packages prefixed by `azure` needed for your application.

In your case, that would likely be [`azure-functions`](https://pypi.org/project/azure-functions/) and [`azure-mgmt-storage`](https://pypi.org/project/azure-mgmt-storage/), although you'll have to do some digging through the docs yourself to find the one that is truly suitable for your requirements.

Comment: Thanks. azure-functions downloaded. Do you know to import it? The simple command "import azure-functions as func" doesn't work because of the '-', and " import azure.functions as func" also doesn't work.

Comment: @swp1 Have you done any further reading from the linked pages? Microsoft provides a pretty detailed [“getting started”](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-cli-python?tabs=azure-cli%2Cbash%2Cbrowser) guide, which includes how to import this library.

Answer (score -1):

Try this cli, it will work:

```
pip install azure-mgmt-storage
```